# Que veut dire « des près » ?

Tags: vocabulaire

> La verdure des près avait laissé place à des landes aux couleurs pourpres.

Je le comprends dans le mesure de *The greenery* **[?]** *had been replaced by a crimson landscape.*

Que faudrait-il mettre à la place de **[?]** ?

Comment: @Evpok Was your original edit not accurate? And why "faudrait-il" instead of "faudrait-on"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Je pense qu'il s'agit d'une [coquille](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coquille_%28typographie%29) et qu'il s'agit en fait de la verdure *des pr​**é**​s*. Donc

> *The greenery **of the meadows** had been replaced by crimson* moors¹.

Et comme cette phrase vient visiblement de la traduction française de *Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*, voici la version originale (p. 57 dans l'édition de poche de Bloomsbury)

> *London was soon far behind them, replaced by neat green **fields** which gave in turn to wide, purpleish moors […]*.

On peut en profiter pour remarquer une faute de traduction : *purple* a ici été traduit par *pourpre* au lieu de *violet*. Le lecteur psychorigide pourra remarquer que *pourpre* n'a pas vraiment de traduction en anglais, même si on peut le traduire par *crimson*, qui est plus proche de *cramoisi*. Une traduction plus exacte aurait été

> La verdure des prés avait laissé place à de vastes landes aux tons violacés.

---

<sub>1. Plus précis que *landscape*.</sub>

Comment: J'ai mal lu le passage. C'est en effet "des prés."